# ibus switching between input methods no longer working on 16.04

Tags: keyboard-layout, ibus

I just upgraded to 16.04 and use ibus to manage multiple keyboard input methods. When I switch between them using my favorite hotkey combination, the icon changes (indicating that has registered), but the actual keys still correspond to US english (or whatever the default system keyboard layout is). How do I make ibus change keyboard layouts?

Answer (score 8):

Just ran into this hiccup when upgrading, and input methods always give me hell whenever I upgrade my distribution, so I thought I'd post the answer here.

Go into the `preferences` interface window (via `preferences` on the panel menu, or alternatively by right clicking the panel icon), navigate to the advanced tab, and then uncheck "use system keyboard layout". This will stop your default system layout overriding ibus when you toggle between layouts.

Answer (score 1):

I found that `~/.config/ibus/bus` owned by root and user can't access it. There should be `IBUS_DEMON_PID` maintained by daemon. So change the owner and restart PC to populate the relationship. That helped me

Comment: this did not work for 22.04 with Mate

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to remove the additional layouts and then re-add them. It helped.